# Make childs for custom post type in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I need help!
I have create a custom post type in my theme and it worked. It has result:

- mysitename.co/collage/harvard

I want new childs that can be added, I mean like this:

- mysitename.co/collage/harvard/address
- mysitename.co/collage/harvard/students

from above where the "address and students" is child from harvard.

My current code is:

```
add_action('init', 'register_segala_Collage');

function register_all_list_Collage() {

    $labels = array( 
        'name' => _x('Collage', 'newborne'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Collage', 'newborne'),
        'all_items' => _x('All Collage', 'newborne'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add List Collage', 'newborne'),
        'add_new_item' => _x('Add List Collage', 'newborne'),
        'edit' => _x('Edit List Collage', 'newborne'),
        'edit_item' => _x('Edit List Collage', 'newborne'),
        'new_item' => _x('New Collage', 'newborne'),
        'view' => _x('View Collage', 'newborne'),
        'view_item' => _x('View Collage', 'newborne'),
        'search_items' => _x('Search Collage', 'newborne'),
        'not_found' => _x('No Collage Found', 'newborne'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x('No Collage Found', 'newborne'),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'Collage', 'newborne' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'Collage' ),
        'query_var' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-nametag',
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail')
    );
    register_post_type( 'Collage', $args );
}
```

How can I do that? is there any code?
Thanks in help.

Comment: Could not understand what is `child of custom post type`. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I mean add a post under current post. As above example I have a custom post mysitename.co/collage/harvard and want to make a new post under that post where will be mysitename.co/collage/harvard/students

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you should try `hierarchical` Custom Post Type. `register_post_type` takes `hierarchical` parameter which is either `true` or `false`. Default value is `false`, that means non-hierarchical custom post type.

Check official documentation: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

**Note:**

Please read the `Note` in the codex page. If you are going to have large number of posts then you might caught in performance issue.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'll try to look at the link you give above.

Comment: Hi Nilambar. I've follow the instruction from the link you give above. And it worked. Thanks again :)